# Real sample data source

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm about to start working on a final project for a college level statistics course. The problem is that I have to analyse real data and so far I haven't got many options. Do you know about any website or perhaps books where I can find data used in previous statistical surveys or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should be more than enough 
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html